# Why aren't RemoteApp icons showing up

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, remoteapp

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server running RDS. I have installed and configured RemoteApp to publish applications with RDS Web Access. When I browse to https://servernname.domain.local/RDWeb I can log in and get to the RemoteApp Programs tab, but there are no icons or apps to click on. I have added a bunch of apps in Remote App manager and they are all enabled for RD Web Access. Also, I am an administrator on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What finally ended up fixing this was setting the identity of the RDSWebAccess App Pool in IIS that was running the RDWeb application. I changed it from ApplicationPoolIdentity to NetworkService and I am now able to see the apps and icons.

Comment: In my case your fix didn't work. However, in attempting it and returning to the previous setting with a reboot it became a fix for me.